# Deploy a Rails 5 app with Docker + Puma + Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, nginx, puma

I am really struggling to deploy my Rails app to my newly created DigitalOcean droplet.

My setup is as follows:

I have a local **Rails 5** app with **Postgres** and **Redis** in Docker containers.

I just want to deploy this to production using **Puma + Nginx** as the webserver.

I cannot manage to do this for the life of me. This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "2"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "${DATABASE_NAME}"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
volumes:
  # This allows the data to persist to disk without being lost on
  # Docker container restarts:
  postgres-data:
    driver: local
```

What is the correct Puma/Nginx configuration to serve such a simple app in production? I've been searching but cannot seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just some advice: Never use Docker for databases in production, unless you absolutely know what you are doing. It can be done, but it's really tricky to do right...

Comment: Yeah I am noticing that too...seems like a pretty bad deal. Data doesn't persist as I'd want it, etc. Might get rid of Docker altogether

Comment: How did you set up Puma etc., and keeping the puma service running? If NGINX is deployed outside Docker, then I dont see why its config would really be different from normal. Make NGINX directly server /public directory, then either use a unix domain socket and make NGINX proxy to that, or if you want a full TCP socket, use that (the default config is for port 3000).

Comment: DaniG2k what's wrong with volumes where you can keep DB data outside of your container? This is how I ended up recently with docker - https://erudinsky.com/2017/05/15/how-to-run-rails-app-with-postgres-puma-and-nginx-in-docker

Answer (score -1):

If your rails app deployed strict to droplet, not in docker, you can try simple configuration such below:

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream your_app {
  server unix:/path_to_app_home/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock 
  fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name yor_domain.tld;

  root /path_to_app/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @your_app;
  location @your_app {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://your_app;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 1G;
}
```

**/path_to_your_app/shared/config/puma.rb**

```
environment "production"

bind  "unix:///path_to_your_app/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock"
pidfile "/path_to_your_app/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "/path_to_your_app/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.state"
directory "/path_to_your_app/current"

workers 1
threads 1,2

daemonize true

activate_control_app 'unix:///path_to_your_app/shared/tmp/sockets/pumactl.sock'

prune_bundler

stdout_redirect "/path_to_your_app/shared/log/puma.stdout.log", "/path_to_your_app/shared/log/puma.stderr.log"
```

Comment: This explicitly does not answer the question